# Simplest solution for a bot which posts to a google hangouts chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

Our house (I live with 5 roommates) uses a google hangouts chat from our phones to communicate various things. Lately we've been discussing some scheduled things, like a rotation for cleaning certain parts of the house, and I thought it would be useful to have a bot announce the pertinent information about the schedule on a hangouts chat.

I'm wondering what the best way to go about this is.

There are two approaches I see:

1) Make an app using google hangouts API which sends messages at the correct interval, connect to this app, use it to chat.

2) Make a google account for a bot which we connect to the hangout, make it send messages at the correct interval.

I like number 2 because I wouldn't have to interfere with the app to change the bot's code, but I'm sort of at a loss for where to start.

Number 1 seems okay, but I'm also not sure I can connect to a google hangouts app on my phone the same way I can just create a chat with friends.

How should I go about doing this task?

Comment: Using Node.js, it's as simple as calling [`xmpp.send('user@gmail.com', 'message')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762036/send-xmpp-notification-from-node-js-script).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I checked the linked question but the answer isn't too specific on how to use it for gmail. I tried to replace it, but I couldn't figure out how to send the hangouts message. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @programmerskillz: I'm still using the [code in that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762036/send-xmpp-notification-from-node-js-script/48097315#48097315) nowadays, and it works fine after I ran `subscribe` once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any preference for the language used to code in?

My immediate thought is to tie into the google calendar for a tasklist and have an app read from that via [**rest**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get).

Then post to the correct hangout (again via rest is probably simplest): you can use [**Fiddler**](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to find what is being done to post to hangouts, or look [**through here**](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/) for an API oriented way to do it.

Let me know if you need more information:)  Hopefully what is here should see you steering in the right direction:)

Answer (score 1):

Google calendar will popup notices on your phone.  You could just share the calendar with your roommate, and skip the hangout notices altogether

Comment: This does not respond to the original question. While your point is valid, this answer does not help others trying to accomplish something similar. For instance, I am currently looking into "botted" hangout notifications for something which happens at arbitrary times. And I want to avoid e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the API, but I believe you will need to create an account for your bot anyways.

If you like Java, you should take a look at their quickstart example : https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java

Answer (score 1):

June 2015 python hangoutsbot. 
Looks like a good bot to start with.
https://github.com/hangoutsbot/hangoutsbot/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I'm not sure how they got around the hard-to-find Google Hangouts Messages API, but this is the option that worked best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the below information will not be useful, but once/if the new hangs out chat becomes available outside of a gsuite account if may provide useful.

For examples with the api here: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/hangouts-chat-samples/tree/master/node/basic-cloud-functions-bot

If using cards instead of plain text this may provide useful: https://github.com/BaReinhard/hangouts-card-helper