# Send XMPP notification from Node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmpp

How can a Node script send a notification via XMPP to a Jabber user (e.g. via Google Hangouts)? I've looked at libraries like [xmpp/client](http://xmppjs.org/client/) but they seem overkill. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: which xmpp server are you using?

Comment: @divsingh: [any XMPP server](https://list.jabber.at) that can send a message to a Google Hangouts user.

Comment: I would suggest that chose an XMPP server that gives you a rest API to send stanza to a particular recipient. See ejabberd administrative API documentation https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/

Comment: as far as I know Hangouts does not support xmpp, while Google Talk service is being shut down. do you have other information?

Comment: however I tried with a node.js script and `talk.google.com` is still accepting XMPP connections

Comment: @beaver: as long as [Pidgin lists Google Talk](https://www.pidgin.im), I'm fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Simplest way to send a message via XMPP in Node

There is probably no other simpler XMPP client library for Node than [node-simple-xmpp](https://github.com/simple-xmpp/node-simple-xmpp).
In this case the minimal Node.js script to send a message to another Jabber user is:

```
var xmpp = require('simple-xmpp');

var jid = 'testjs@xmpp.jp';
var pwd = 'xyz';
var server = 'xmpp.jp';
var port = 5222;

xmpp.on('online', function(data) {
    console.log('Connected with JID: ' + data.jid.user);
    xmpp.send('testjs@007jabber.com', 'hello! time is '+new Date(), false);
});

xmpp.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error("error:", JSON.stringify(err));
});

xmpp.connect({
    jid: jid,
    password: pwd,
    host: server,
    port: port
});
```

If the two account have never spoken together, a preliminary 'subscribe' is also required:

```
xmpp.subscribe('testjs@007jabber.com');
```

As you can see in package.json *node-simple-xmpp* lib has a dependency on [node-xmpp-client] (https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/tree/node-xmpp/packages/node-xmpp-client).

#### Usage with Google Talk/Hangouts

The script above is working (tested) also with Google Talk/Hangouts, you just have to replace `xmpp.jp`server with `talk.google.com` and use a Google account. Turn on https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps to enable Node.js script to sign in with Google account.

### Other XMPP libraries

As of https://npms.io/search?q=node-xmpp there are a few other XMPP Client libraries for Node, however almost all of them are dependent on *node-xmpp-client* or limited to BOSH connection (polling over HTTP).

One interesting lib for those used to *Strophe.js* on client side seems [node-strophe](https://github.com/Iperity/node-strophe). It is based on [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) release 1.0.2 which is a library for applications that run in any browser. Unfortunately that version didn't support other than BOSH (see [Strophe.js changelog](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)), websocket is available only since release 1.1.0.

### Exploring alternatives without specific XMPP libraries

An alternative solution without specific XMPP libraries could be using [Net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), but in this case you need to manage all XMPP interactions to establish the connection to the server, see [https://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Programming_XMPP_Clients](https://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Programming_XMPP_Clients#Secure_connections) .

Below is a very raw example of script trying to initiate the connection with a Jabber server using *Net module*:

```
var net = require('net');

var jid = 'testjs@xmpp.jp';
var pwd = 'xyz';
var server = 'xmpp.jp';
var port = 5222;

var msg = '<stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0" to="'+server+'">';

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(port, server, function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write(msg);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
});
```

You can see in the console log the correct answer of Jabber server, however from then on it's a mess: you should begin exchanging TLS messages (see https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#tls)

### Conclusions

I think the only feasible alternative is the first one using *node-simple-xmpp* library.

Comment: I tried with two different `<user>@gmail.com` accounts, which are both using Hangouts fine, and got `XMPP authentication failure` each time. I had enabled less secure apps and set the server to `talk.google.com`. Thoughts?

Comment: I also tried with different accounts and it worked; did you use the minimal script I suggested?

Comment: In addition, if the two have never spoken together, the 'subscribe' is also required

Comment: Never mind, it was a suspicious IP issue. Saw it after I logged in as the sender - there was a "Warning: Google prevented a suspicious attempt to sign in to your account using your password.". Now the script connects, but hangs at `xmpp.send`.

Comment: I'm using the simple script and the users had talked via hangouts.google.com. Turns out I had to run subscribe (once) anyway. Glad we solved it, and thanks for the answer!