# Connect node app to Openfire

Tags: node.js, xmpp, openfire, node-xmpp

I have my nodejs server and my Openfire server, I wanted to connect both and found out that there is a plugin for nodejs in Openfire. I have install it and placed my node project in /opt/openfire/nodejs.

I have not found any documentation of what steps should I follow next. I have installed xmpp.js library too but don't know how should I connect it to the server through it. Neither do I know how to access or what is the url to my node app through openfire.

On the system settings in Openfire I have written the following properties so that in the Nodejs tab an entry appears

js.folder.server server.js

js.folder.server.path /opt/openfire/nodejs/folder

I am really new to this and haven't found any help while searching

Comment: I don't know the real purpose to integrate node.js and Openfire, however I suggest to take into consideration node.js pure XMPP libraries (independent from specific XMPP server like Openfire). Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762036/send-xmpp-notification-from-node-js-script/48097315#48097315